# How to fix a Failed Package Operation Error?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

Launched the software center and I am getting this error:

```
installArchives() failed: E: Invalid archive signature    
E: Internal error, could not locate member control.tar.{gzbz2xzlzma}    
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/libwayland-egl1-mesa_10.1.3-0ubuntu0.1_i386.deb    
E: Invalid archive signature    
E: Internal error, could not locate member control.tar.{gzbz2xzlzma}    
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/libgles2-mesa_10.1.3-0ubuntu0.1_i386.deb    
debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory    
E: Invalid archive signature    
E: Internal error, could not locate member control.tar.{gzbz2xzlzma}    
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/libwayland-egl1-mesa_10.1.3-0ubuntu0.1_i386.deb    
E: Invalid archive signature    
E: Internal error, could not locate member control.tar.{gzbz2xzlzma}    
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/libgles2-mesa_10.1.3-0ubuntu0.1_i386.deb    
debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory    
E: Invalid archive signature    
E: Internal error, could not locate member control.tar.{gzbz2xzlzma}    
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/libwayland-egl1-mesa_10.1.3-0ubuntu0.1_i386.deb    
E: Invalid archive signature    
E: Internal error, could not locate member control.tar.{gzbz2xzlzma}    
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/libgles2-mesa_10.1.3-0ubuntu0.1_i386.deb    
debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory    
dpkg-deb: error: `/var/cache/apt/archives/libwayland-egl1-mesa_10.1.3-0ubuntu0.1_i386.deb' is not a  debian format archive    
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libwayland-egl1-mesa_10.1.3-0ubuntu0.1_i386.deb (--unpack):    
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2    
dpkg-deb: error: `/var/cache/apt/archives/libgles2-mesa_10.1.3-0ubuntu0.1_i386.deb' is not a debian format archive    
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libgles2-mesa_10.1.3-0ubuntu0.1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:    
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libwayland-egl1-mesa_10.1.3-0ubuntu0.1_i386.deb    
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libgles2-mesa_10.1.3-0ubuntu0.1_i386.deb    
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libegl1-mesa-drivers:i386:    
 libegl1-mesa-drivers:i386 depends on libwayland-egl1-mesa (= 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.1); however:    
 Version of libwayland-egl1-mesa:i386 on system is 10.1.0-4ubuntu5.
```